# Using "Select by location" with percentage

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, select-by-location

I have two layers, one layer with isochrones with representing driving times from certain locations and one layer with postal code area's.

What I want to know is which postal code area can be reached with 5 minutes of driving time. The problem is that some postal code areas are crossing with the isochrones layer by a very small amount.

I wanted to ask if it's possible to select the postal code area's which are covered by for example 30% so the area's that can be reached within 5 minutes is more accurate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Overlap analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#overlap-analysis) to add overlap area and percentage columns
2. [Select](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) or [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) those with a percentage >=30

With my data the expression is

```
"Multi-ring buffer (constant distance)_pc" >= 30
```

[image]